# Using Github with out local repository

Tags: git, github, git-svn, github-api

I want to build a web application to upload program files and save directly on github. Is it possible to upload files with out having local repository(clone)? Is there a developer API I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You'll want to take a look at the [GitHub DB API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/), which should show you how to communicate with the GitHub API for your particular use cases.